# Sentence construction using went, did go and had gone

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one sentence is correct to say? Please explain the situation where I can use below sentences.

a) Where you went, I have been looking for you.

b) Where you had gone, I have been looking for you.

c) Where did you go, I have been looking for you.

Answer (score 1):

C is the closest to correct, thought it really should be two sentences:

> Where did you go? I have been looking for you.

Comment: But Why two other s are incorrect? . Please explain the meanings of sentence i mean can we use them in any context?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking a direct question, you need an auxiliary verb and your question should be like this:

> Where did you go? I have been looking for you.

You may also use:

*Where were you?* or *Where have you been?*

The first part of the first sentence (also the second one) is not a WH question and it somehow means:

> The place you went, I have been looking for you.

If you are insisting on using `where you went`, you can use it like this:

> I want to know where you went / have been.

In this sentence where is a subordinate conjunction.

---

By the way, I think the best time to say "I have been looking for you" is very soon after you find that person. Otherwise, since you are no longer looking for him/her, it would be better to use *I was looking for you* or even *I had been looking for you* (which is less common).